# LINQ where condition filtering

Tags: c#, linq

```
String Sex = getSex(); // return M or F
String[] members = getMembers(); // return member codes in array or null
//if members array is null, no filtering for member codes
var query = from tb in MemberTable
            where tb.sex.Equals(Sex) && 
                  (members != null ? members.Contains(tb.membercode) : true)
            select tb;
```

The code doesn't return correct result. It returns all members no matter what `members[]` is.

Actually the original LINQ is complex so if there are any other possible solutions, I do not want to write the following:

```
if (members == null){ /*LINQ1*/ }
else { /*LINQ2*/ }
```

which is not a good coding style.
Any suggestion for solving this problem?

Comment: Does your ORM support the ternary operator? I've never tried with any ORM.. :/ What is the SQL that results from this LINQ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var query = MemberTable.Where(x=>x.sex.Equals(Sex))

if (members != null)
     query = query.Where(x=>members.Contains(x.membercode))

//use your query
query.ToList();
```

OR

```
var query = from tb in MemberTable
        where tb.sex.Equals(Sex) && 
              (members == null || members.Contains(tb.membercode))
        select tb;
```

I prefer the first.

Comment: I definitely prefer the first. That's best solution, because it will evaluate `members != null` only once, not for every item.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. May I ask some issues about method 1?
It seems there are some records will be scanned twice. Any performance issue there compare to method 2?

Comment: There will be no records scanned multiple times. What LINQ does is just building an IQuerable object, so you can add as many stuff to it as you want. It is only executed when you _use_ it (ToList in this example). Until you start consuming results it is just a query object and nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Since `||` short-circuits, you should be able to do this:

```
var query = from tb in MemberTable
    where tb.sex.Equals(Sex) && 
          (members == null || members.Contains(tb.membercode))
    select tb;
```

The `(members == null || members.Contains(tb.membercode))` subexpression will be `true` if `members` is `null`, so `Contains` would not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<ModelName>();
list = ctx.MemberTable
    .Where(c => c.sex==Sex)
    .Where(c => c.membercode==true)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I think you are right. But I was just trying to tell that nested where would work well, otherwise syntactically it is correct. He could use his logical condition in it.

Comment: Very well. I've fixed your compilation error and your formatting.